# What is the correct syntax for using gdal_rasterize with a PostGIS datasource

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql

I have a multipolygon layer in PostGIS and I would like to use gdal_rasterize to generate a raster. I cannot find the correct syntax to specify PostGIS as the data source.

```
$ gdal_rasterize -a labor_force_2013_12 -l unemployment_by_county PG:'host=localhost user=usernamehere' out.tif
ERROR 4: `out.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.`
```

All the gdal_rasterize examples I can find online use a shapefile as the data source but the `gdal_rasterize` man page says that the `src_datasource` parameter can be "Any OGR supported readable datasource"

Comment: it looks like you're missing the dbname in your PG connection string. It should be something like: `PG:'host=localhost dbname=yourDBname user=usernamehere'`

Comment: What version of GDAL? (gdalinfo --version ?). Before 1.8, gdal_rasterize ould not create a new raster at all. You could only burn into an existing *.tif.